# In angularJS, after disabling a field it loses focus. How do I manually put the focus back?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

http://jsfiddle.net/0n6tzcpb/

I have the following fiddle with just an input type text and a button that disables then enables the field after 1 second.

I have tried putting

```
   var myEl = document.getElementById('myId');
   var angularEl = angular.element(myEl);
   angularEl.focus();
```

after line 10, but it gives the following error

```
<a class='gotoLine' href='#[object Error] { ... }'>[object Error] { ... }</a>
```

If I enable jQuery in the fiddle then the error goes away, but still doesn't work.

Comment: From the [link shown in the error](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/docs/error/jqLite/nosel): _"Looking up elements via selectors is not supported by jqLite!...In order to keep Angular small, Angular implements only a subset of the selectors in jqLite. This error occurs when a jqLite instance is invoked with a selector other than this subset."_. So looks like you can't use `angular.element` to select with an ID selector...

Answer (score 1):

In my project I managed to solve it with

```
   $shouldDisable = false;
   $timeout(function() {
      var element = angular.element("#id");
      element.focus()
   });
```

In the jsfiddle I don't know why this didn't work. The $timeout is necessary so it gets executed after everything else.